# Javascript select all HTML input fields with array style name

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that I am building and would like to have a javascript to select and manipulate all of the fields that are within the named array:

```
<input type="text" name="location[street]" value required />
<input type="text" name="location[city]" value required />
<input type="text" name="location[zip]" value required />
<input type="text" name="location[state]" value required />
```

How can I build a selector for javascript to toggle all of the elements disabled state?

Jquery is possible but not preferred. I would prefer a method that would work without libraries - such as document.getElementsByName().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) doesn't have support for a selector to get an element by an *attribute*, like jQuery would be `input[name^="location"]`([docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)). So, try this:

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('input');

for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++)
{
    if (els[i].name.indexOf("location") > -1)
    {
        els[i].disabled = true;
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhcgolds/t2zo6010/2/). I will be glad to hear that I'm wrong and there is a way for doing this only using a selector.

Anyway, you can use the `fieldset` and make your code more semantic by disabling only the fieldset, if you like: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhcgolds/gLq7k47a/).

**UPDATE**

In order to disable all `textarea` and `select` elements as well, just include those tags on the selector:

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea, select');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhcgolds/t2zo6010/3/)

Comment: This works, however, it is not including any of the TEXTAREA or SELECT form elements (and this is my fault for not mentioning them in the question).  If I am going to have to loop through all of the INPUT elements, I might as well just loop through all of the form elements and do the same comparison.

Comment: Changed querySelectorAll() to document.getElementById('form_id').elements, so that non-input form types could be selected as well... but otherwise this answer is correct.

Comment: Is using document.querySelectorAll('input, textarea, select') more efficient than using the form.elements?

Comment: Well, in this case I think `form.elements` should fit your needs to, but I really don't know which is better in this case. What you can do is set a class for all your elements starting with `location` in name tag, then you select them with `.location-element`. In this case `querySelectorAll` will make more sense.

Comment: use a variable for the length so you are not calculating it over and over.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to queryselector would be getElementsByTagName

```
var i;
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
 var name =  inputs[i].getAttribute("name");
    if(name.indexOf("location") > -1)
    {
    inputs[i].disabled = true;
        console.log(name);

    }
}
```

[link to JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karthickj25/qe2fndva/)